# Find all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $x^{y}=y^{y-x}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Find all $x,y\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $ x^{y}=y^{y-x} $.

I have found the solutions $(1,1)$ and $(2,4)$. I've been trying to prove that there aren't any more. I tried splitting the cases by parity, but nothing interesting seemed to come out.

I also tried rearranging it into:

$x=y^{\frac{y-x}{y}}$.

Is there any way to proceed with this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all Pairs of Integers $(x,y)$ , $x \gt y \ge 2$ such that $x^y=y^{x-y}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992626/find-all-pairs-of-integers-x-y-x-gt-y-ge-2-such-that-xy-yx-y)

Comment: @Saad: That’s not the same equation though, is it (although similar methods may apply)?

Comment: @Mindlack Indeed, I'm not sure it can be called a duplicate, but the idea of setting $y=tx$ comes from the comment there, after which one actually reaches $y = t^{-\frac 1t}$ so the question becomes the possibly easier : for which rationals $t$ is it true that $t^{-\frac 1t}$ is an integer?

Comment: Hint: Using Maple (still running) the first few solutions are x=1, y=1 x=2, y=4 x=9, y=27 x=64, y=256 x=625, y=3125 Interesting. All powers of the same prime.

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon: how do you get this? By the same method, I can find infinitely many solutions parametrized by $t=y/x$ (an integer).

Comment: @Mindlack I'm sorry : I actually set $x=ty$ instead : then one gets $(ty)^y  = y^{y-ty}$, which then becomes $t^yy^y = y^{-ty} y^{y}$ which then becomes $t^y = y^{-ty}$. Taking the $y$th root gives $t = y^{-t}$, so $t^{-\frac 1t} = y$. Having said that, an answer covered $y=tx$ below more successfully anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the function can be written as
$$ \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^{y} = y^{x} $$
If you let $t = \frac{y}{x}$ then we can get
$$ t^{t} = y $$
So if you apply $y = t^{t}$ and $x = t^{t - 1}$ with $t$ an integer you get infinite pairs of solutions.
Furthermore, if $t$ is not an integer then $t = q/p$ which is irreducible.
Then $y = (q/p)^{q/p}$ is an integer so $y^{p} = (q/p)^q$ is an integer, which is not possible.
So $(x, y)$ is a solution to the equation iff $(x, y) = (t^{t-1}, t^t)$ with $t$ an integer, and there are infinitely many pairs.